# Share object between JavaEE applications on the same JVM (using JNDI)

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, wildfly

I'm running a JBoss AS 7.1.3.Final installation with a lot of applications. One of those applications provides common resources and functionallities used by all applications (let's call it **framework**). I'm also planning to move to WildFly 8, if this is an useful information for your answer.

All applications should only be accessible, if the framework is available (up and running). My current implementation to achive this dependency is not that nice** and as I'm currently re-designing some parts of the environment, I'm looking for a much neater solution for it. My first idea was to create some kind of a manager which will be instantiated by the application server and is available to all applications. So after an application is started, it could register itself on the manager and as soon as the framework is up, the applications will be notified.

Is this possible using the JNDI of the JVM where all applications + framework are running? How must this be implemented? It's really hard to find useful information about how the JNDI works and what is possible with it. Do you have any other, simplier ideas, how to share a class instance between applications?

Thank you.

** Currently I'm using a EJB-timer in the applications and a singleton EJB in the framework. The framework is available as soon as the EJB lookup succeeds.

--

**Edit #1**
Some more informations as requested by Nikos Paraskevopoulos

- One functionionality that is provided by the framework is the *maintenance mode*. The applications will check, right after startup, if it is blocked for normal users. It will also receive notifications about planned maintenances. (central DB, the application has no rights on it)
- Common stylesheets or layouts are deployed with the framework.
- The user informations are provided by the framework. (central DB, the application has no rights on it)

The main problem is: How could I avoid any timers? I have no idea, how I could ensure, that the framework is up before everything else.

Comment: Sounds like a ejb jar you'd include in your war deployment and have the framework class(es) annotated `@Startup`?

Comment: That's how it is implemented right now. The framework classes, that provide the common functionallities are EJBs with @Startup on it. But the applications might be deployed before the framework. Thats why I have to use the timer in the applications. But I think thats not a really nice solution right now.

Comment: Well, I'd deploy the ejbs inside each war. So they are available whenever a application starts. Duplicates the classes and bloats the heap. But at least it always works.

Comment: @grubi: Check out the editted reply

Comment: Sounds to me like that this should all be part of one EAR and not isolated applications. You might treat them as isolated applications during development, but in deployment you package them up in one ear. That sanitizes versioning too.

Comment: @Gimby I mentioned in another comment, that packaging them in one EAR (or specify the framwork as a dependency of each application) has other drawbacks: e.g. if I have to change one application or the framework, each application requres a re-deployment. Do I have any false information on this and I just failed while testing this?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed your comment. Yes what you mention is a consequence; I'm not saying it is a negative consequence though, application deployment should be controlled and restricted; that prevents damaging mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- JBoss has the capability of ordering deployments according to their dependencies. See [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-deploy/configuring-jboss-as-7-deployment-order) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343732/jboss-as-7-deployment-order-and-timing). So, if all the "applications" depend explicitly on the "framework", your problem *may* be solved.
- It seems you have a quite strongly coupled configuration. Would it be possible to decouple them, e.g. provide the service through web services (SOAP/REST)? Of course this introduces extra overhead for the communication and the refactoring...
- JNDI can be seen (very roughly) as a name to object map shared across the applications. As such, you may share stuff through it. But I do not see how will you solve the timing problem, i.e. wait for a service to be available before using it from the "applications". The manager component you mention can be placed in JNDI.

This is not a complete answer, but it would not fit as a comment either. Maybe if you presented more details on the nature of the applications, the frameworks used etc, you could get more specific answers.

Good luck anyway

---

**Edit #1:**

- *Maintenance mode*: This may be nice for using with JNDI. A servlet filter that intercepts every (applicable) request will check a global JNDI name; if it is not found (i.e. framework not started) or it is `false`, it will short-circuit the processing of the request, sending back the "maintenance mode" page. The framework will have to set a `Boolean` in the global JNDI name as soon as it has started and maintain its value, i.e. set it to `false` if maintenance mode is active.
- *Common stylesheets*: This is really covered by the maintenance mode flag, I believe. *Layouts*: It depends on the view technology/layouts technology.
- *User information*: This is a good candidate for SOAP/REST implementation. It is not expected to be called frequently, so I assume overhead will not matter.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I can't use #1, as it will introduce other problems (e.g each application requires an restart if the framework changes). Using web services (#2) might be an option that did not come into my mind. I have to think about it. I will edit my question and add more information.

Comment: +1 for the additional interface. From the OP's edit this seems like the most stable and appropriate solution.

Comment: Your solution concerning the maintenance mode is just genius. I didn't come up with the solution to simply write a boolean to the JNDI to signal the availability of the framework. A servlet filter was already planned with the same reason you mentioned too (intercept the requests). **Edit**: No additional requirement, after I looked through my notes again. Solution accepted. Thank you :)

Comment: One more thought about maintenance: It may not be appropriate to bring the system down while requests are being processed. So besides the boolean you may also need a (synchronized/atomic) counter that counts active requests; when the boolean is false no more requests are accepted, but the system does not go down until the counter reaches zero. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think OSGi is the technology you should consider. Basically you have an OSGi container with applications (called bundles) which provide or consume services. So you would have a framework service which is consumed by all applications. JBoss is an OSGi container, as far as I know.